# поиск значений без повторов с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

помогите написать регулярное выражение, которое проверит значение: в переменной может быть указан один или несколько кодов без повторов через запятую, без пробелов, из следующих кодов:

1,2,3,4,5,8,33

```
^(1|2|3|4|5|8|33)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```
^(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)(?:[1-58]|33)(?:,(?:[1-58]|33))*$
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/IDeWeX/1).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)` - разрешены только уникальные целые числа
- `(?:[1-58]|33)` - число от 1 до 5, 8 или 33
- `(?:,(?:[1-58]|33))*` - ноль и более повторов последовательности из запятой и числа от 1 до 5, 8 или 33
- `$` - конец строки.